# Oracle - Entity Framework - Procedimientos Almacenados - Cursores

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, cursor

alguna idea para solucionar lo siguiente:
Escenario Actual.

Tengo procedimientos almacenados en Oracle los cuales retornan el resultado de un Select en un cursor.
Este procedimiento lo mapeo con EF, lo cual genera automáticamente una clase compleja en base a los columnas del cursor retornado desde el SP
Por cada SP mapeado, en el `web.config` se adiciona una definición *gigante* como esta:

```
    <storedProcedure schema="CLI_WEB" name="PCK_APP_OBJ_MOVIMIENTO.P_OBJ_MOVIMIENTO_A">
      <refCursor name="O_RESULTADO">
        <bindInfo mode="Output" />
        <metadata columnOrdinal="0" columnName="ID_TABLE" providerType="Decimal" allowDBNull="true" nativeDataType="Number" />
        <metadata columnOrdinal="1" columnName="MENSAJE" providerType="Varchar2" allowDBNull="true" nativeDataType="Varchar2" />
        <metadata columnOrdinal="2" columnName="MENSAJE_EX" providerType="Varchar2" allowDBNull="true" nativeDataType="Varchar2" />
        <metadata columnOrdinal="3" columnName="EXITO" providerType="Varchar2" allowDBNull="true" nativeDataType="Varchar2" />
      </refCursor>
    </storedProcedure>
```

Como podrán apreciar es una linea por cada columna del cursor y tengo SP que retornan un cursor con 20 columnas o mas, lógicamente esto no me parece bueno, básicamente por dos razones:

- EL web config llegaría a crecer en el orden de los miles de lineas de código, lo cual no lo veo mantenible.
- Si se hace un update, por simplemente modificar una columna del cursor del SP tendría que volver a distribuir todo incluyendo el *web config* (prefiero evitar distribuir el `web.config`)

Ahora bien, lo que necesito es lo siguiente: Básicamente ver la manera de que todas esas líneas de código que se adiciona al `web.config` por cada procedimiento almacenado, dejen de estar en el *web config*, ver la manera de ponerlas en código embebido o alguna otra manera, lo importante es que ya dejen de aparecer en el `web.config`.

**Nota.** Es muy importante, por la arquitectura que llevo, seguir trabajando con procedimientos almacenados; no puedo cambiar esa manera de trabajo, solo acceso a procedimientos almacenados que retornan un cursor.

De antemano gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola. No estas usando un archivo .edmx? Donde tienes definido tu capa de EF??. En el mismo proyecto Web? Te recomiendo hagas separación e capas en distintos ensamblados.

Comment: Sip es EDMX, tengo un proyecto libreria de clases para el EF, luego la dll la llevo al sitio web, pero todo el codigo del app.config del proyeccto de biblioteca de clases debe ser copiado al sitio web config del proyecto web, ya que esta dll sacara estos parametros del web.config

Comment: Hola. Pero toda la información de las tablas y procedimientos almacenados junto con sus mapeos a las clases .NET se encuentran en el edmx. No hace falta ponerlas en el web.config. Lo que se establece en ese archivo config son las cadenas de conexión y otros datos(como la seccion de entiryframework) que pueda usar ese ensamblado de acceso a datos. Te lo comento porque hace poco he realizado un proyecto asi h no tengo problema.

Comment: Si abres el .edmx con el notepad veras que no es más que un archivo xml

Comment: Hola Sergio, no se si trabajaste con EF mapeando precedimientos almacenados que retornan un cursor como parámetro de salida, en este caso, es donde se genera lo mencionado en el web config, no son mapeos de tablas, vistas, o procedimientos almacenados que tienen datos de tipo primitivo como salida, aqui el punto clave es que el procedimiento almacenado retorna cursores como parametro de salida out.

Comment: La verdad no sabia eso y por lo que he investigado es necesario que se genere en ese fichero todas esas lindas de código. Ver https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featImplRefCursor.htm#ODPNT319

Comment: Si pues es una pena que tenga que ser asi, el web.config se hace gigante, por eso quiero ver la manera de poner esas lineas de codigo en cualquier otro lado menos en el web.config